# How to get the resultant array from a Mongoid::Criteria without an "each" block

Tags: arrays, mongoid, criteria

Our application uses ajax very heavily and as a result of this we have statements like `var items = #{@items.to_json}` in all our views. Now `@items` is being set in the controller as `@items=Item.all`. The problem is that `@items` is a `Mongoid::Criteria` and it doesn't have a `.to_json` method. So, it's throwing up an error while rendering the view. Is there an easy way to convert this criteria object into an array without using code like `@items.collect {|i| i}`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the `#entries` method in criteria to do request:

```
@items = Item.all.entries
```

Comment: Hello shingara, can that work in opposite way?
I mean convert array to Mongoid::Criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the solution I'm applying is to transform in an Array, so I can still use the power of criteria and then get the results. After you transform to array, you can transform in json

@items.to_a #give you the records

@items.to_a.to_json # give you the final json

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, at least since Mongoid 4.0, there's the `as_json` instance method:

```
Person.where(:title => "Sir").as_json
```

Reference: http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#as_json-instance_method